# Passing parameter to open view

Tags: view, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to pass a parameter to the view and open it. and I try something like this.

```java
MyView view = new MyView(parameter);
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(viewID);
```

but get an error message "Plug-in was unable to instantiate class 'view'"

How can I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showView` always creates a new instance of the view and requires that the class has a no parameter constructor, you can't create the view class in the way you show.

`showView` returns the `IViewPart` that it created so you can do:

```java
IViewPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(viewID);

((MyView)part).setParameter(parameter);
```

where `setParameter` is a method you add to your view class.

Comment: Thanks, but Since I have to display the parameter in the view.
how can I refresh view after loaded the parameter?

Comment: I think this will be called before the view is shown. In any case calling `setInput` or `refresh` on a Tree/Table Viewer will refresh.

Comment: it open the view before the method being called. and I am sorry that I cannot get how to refresh?

Comment: is it add "MyView.refresh();" at the end of the "setParameter()"?

Comment: There is no special way to refresh a view you just set values in the controls in the view.

Comment: Oh....I used tableViewer template. 
tableViewer viewer;
viewer.refresh();

solved the problem.
Thanks